# Pickled class contains data only while application is running

Tags: python, class, pickle

I've got a script that does something, saves result to class variable then pickles this variable.
I've also got another function that loads this pickle file and reads it.

If I open this script, run first function (pickle to file) then function with unpickling then it runes fine and I can read all the data

If I open this script, run first function (pickle to file), close application, open it again and load the same file that was pickled earlier the class contains only default values

Example of code:

```
class test_class:
    table = ["a","b","c"]

def f1():
    test_variable = test_class()
    test_variable.table.append("d")

    file = open(file, "wb")
    pickle.dump(test_variable, file, -1)
    file.close()

def f2():
    file = open(file, "rb")
    new_test_variable = pickle.load(file)
    print new_test_variable.table
    file.close()
```

Working:

```
f1()
f2()
```

Output of that:

```
a,b,c,d
```

Not working:

```
f1()
[closing program, reopening program]
f2()
```

Output of not working:

```
a,b,c
```

What is wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a class attribute by defining `table` on the classes top-level. Only instance attributes will be pickled.

So define the attribute:

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.table = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: I did domething simmilar with my class and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you should have a look at the dill module:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill/0.1a1

you need to install the dill module and change `import pickle` to `import dill as pickle`, then everything should work. This is because dill extends pythons pickle.

> **Dill is capable of pickling the following standard types:**
>
> - none, type, bool, int, long, float, complex, str, unicode,
> - tuple, list, dict, file, buffer, builtin,
> - both old and new style classes,
> - instances of old and new style classes,
> - set, frozenset, array, lambda,
> - standard functions, functions with yields, nested functions
> - wrapperdescriptor, xrange, slice,

Something else:

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

also:

> Try not to name variables as:
>
> - str
> - int
> - file
> - and so on

So you should change

```
def f2():
    file = open(file, "rb")
    new_test_variable = pickle.load(file)
    print new_test_variable.table
    file.close()
```

To:

```
def f2():
    with open('filelocation', "rb") as pickleFile:
        new_test_variable = pickle.load(pickleFile)
        print new_test_variable.table
```